# Get the last saved value to the dropdown from the database on update

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, selectedvalue

I would like to update my database content and I first need to check the last saved value to my user and allow him to update his data !!!

here is my code but it doesn't work !!!

```
$form->dropDownList($persons,'sex', array(''=>"Choose" ,'M'=>'Man', 'F'=>'Woman'), array('options' => array($person_data['sex'] => array('selected'=>true))));

print_r($person_data['sex']) is showing me the right value from DB ('M' or 'F').
```

can any one show me how to do this please. i already check here but most of solution propose just show with a particular index but it's not working for me.

Comment: there a lot of dropdownList in form but some of them worked well but not other ! it's seems like the problem was only the quote used. i tried "Man"=>"Man" and so one and it worked and gave me the latest data from my database as default selected value. Most of time Yii documentation used single (''). It's my Server configuration or PHP version (PHP5.3.3) or i need to use

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?In the options array,

```
array('options' => array($YourModel->attribute =>  array('selected' => true)))
```

Just a Guess!!

Answer (score -1):

Bellow code will help you

```
   <?php
   echo $form->dropDownList($YorModel,'sex', array('M'=>'Man', 'F'=>'Woman'),array('empty'=>'----Select Gender-----'));
   ?>
```

Comment: Hearaman, This is going to put "--Select Gender---" in the input field. But it's not really what i want to do. I would like that my data ('M' or 'F') getting from database automatically put 'Man' or 'Woman' in this field. because the data already exist in my database and i want to show it to my user and let him change it if need. It is for update field. Your answer is working when the register for the first time. Thanks.